# Use join() and where() with update()

Tags: yii

Can i use join() and where() with update() in query builder?

```
$q = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->update('table',array('a'=>0))
->join('join statement')
->where('where statement')
->query();
```

I get error like this

```
Call to a member function join() on a non-object in ...
```

edit:
if i test

```
$q = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->update('table',array('a'=>0));
die($q);
```

i see result 0 so

I think update(),execute sql statement so i can't use join() and where().

Comment: Have you tried using cdbcriteria

Comment: What is your join statement? what is your where statement?

Comment: it doesnt matter join and where statemant. i test simple where and join statement

Comment: how to use cdbcriteria in query builder?

Answer (score 1):

Join in Yii is not a method, you do not use it like this:

`->join('tbl_profile p', 'u.id=p.user_id')`

but like this:

`->join = 'tbl_profile p';`

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for an answer to the same question. When I couldn't find one, I checked the source code.

Yii's CDBCommand::update method disregards any join that you might add earlier to your CDBCommand (see source here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/CDbCommand.php#L1265).

So, the simple answer is that you can't make a join in an update method on CDBCommand. That leaves turning to CDBCriteria or, if that really isn't an option, writing an UPDATE query in native SQL and executing it using a CDBCommand. Something like:

```
$command = $this->dbConnection->createCommand('[Your native SQL UPDATE query]');
$command->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a format

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->update('tbl_user u',array('a'=>0))
    ->join('tbl_profile p', 'u.id=p.user_id')
    ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
    ->queryRow();
```

May be you missing conidition for join.

Or use [cdbcriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria)